# Number of Hamilton paths in an extremely dense undirected simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

What is the fastest way (algorithm) to calculate the number of Hamilton paths in an extremely dense undirected simple graph (approximately 99.99% edges are connected)?

I was thinking of the following way :

First, calculate the number of Hamilton paths in the complete graph.

Remove one edge at a time, but I am not able to figure out how many paths would be reduced on removing an edge. Also how to prevent double counting while removing the edges ?

I came across a similar question here but that was about Hamilton cycles and not paths, I hope that changes the question significantly. Also the answers were not quite clear, hence this post.

Comment: how many vertices?

Comment: Say around 10^5 vertices, out of which <10 vertices are not connected.

Comment: @John: Just curious -- the number of Hamiltonian paths on $10^5$ vertices will be huge, why is such precision needed?

Comment: Is there a way to generalize it, instead of thinking 10^5 as a number ?